# How many $6$-integer subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 20\}$ have no consecutive integers?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have to determine how many six-integer subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 20\}$ are possible if no two consecutive integers are in a set.

Comment: Inclusive of $1$ and $20$, or exclusive?

Comment: inclusive of 1 and 20 sir.

Answer (score 4):

Let's do it the other way around. Inserting $6$ marked items separately into a row of $14$ other items (thus into $15$ "gaps" before, between and after) can be done in $\dbinom {15}{6} = \dfrac{15!}{9!\,6!}$ ways. This leaves us with a rows of $20$ items, which can be numbered eg L-to-R, with $6$ distinct and non-adjacent as required.

Comment: Probably the correct answer, but can you formulate it clearer why each collection $6$ out of $15$ can be $1-1$ transformed into a collection $6$ out of $20$ in the required way ? Maybe, at an example collection ...

Comment: I think my closing sentence does that - you end up with 20 items, 6 marked, none of those adjacent., no other restrictions. Tweaked the wording a little

Comment: To convince me, which collection $6$ out of $15$ corresponds with $$[7, 9, 12, 14, 18, 20]$$ for example

Comment: Numbering the gaps left to right (gap 1 is before any static item), you're inserting into  $7,8,10,11,14,15$

Comment: @Peter In your notation, subtract $[0,1,2,3,4,5]$.